# WireMockServer change mapping directory at runtime

Tags: wiremock

We have test suites defined where different suites require different stubs. The stubs are recorded individually and stored in different folders e.g.

```
/parent
  + stub1
    + mappings
    + __files
  + stub2
    + mappings
    + __files
  ...
```

While starting the wiremock server we specify the mapping directory something like :

```
WireMockServer wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(
                WireMockConfiguration.wireMockConfig()
                                     .usingFilesUnderDirectory(rootPath));

wireMockServer.start();
```

How can the instance be reset and register a different mapping folder at runtime ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported actually.
You will need to stop/restart WireMock to update the folders. 
Why do you need to change the mappings folder path at runtime? if you give more context I can help you :) 
Regards

Comment: Hi.
Very late reply to your question, but I have a use case :
I've started to use Wiremock today
I need to tune several mocked endpoints for a load test.
Being familiar with JS development environments, I've naturally searched for a watch option
Without having it, I'll have to search for a shell tool that doing it for me, but it would be better to have Wiremock supporting it out of the box :p